# formatting a hidden value in an excell worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I enter my hours every week and email to employer. Within my worksheet for accounting and tax purposes I have a cell that is a running total of my income.  I would like to mask that cell so no one can see the dollar value, but becomes visible to me when I hover my mouse over it.

I have seen this done and know it can be done, but for the life of me cannot find a formula to do this.

Your help would be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: For that cell, make the font color the same as the cell's background color.  Then put the cell's value in a Comment.

Comment: You can hide the column/row and protect the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "MouseOver" event or anything like that. But you can use another easy trick:

```
=HYPERLINK("$23.45","Income")
```

Will just show `Income`. But if you hover over it you will see `$23.45 - Click once...` like a comment. Having your formula as the target of the hyperlink and the [friendly name] as any text like "Income" or whatever.